# How do I get a data from one table to another but with calculations?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench, workbench

I have two tables: "Customer" and "Order". The "Customer" table has an attribute called `noOfPurchases`, and the "Order" table has an attribute called `quantity`.

How do I UPDATE the Customer table in the way that, every customer will have a sum of their all orders quantity. For example one time there is a order of 5 items and another record with same `CustomerID` with 12 items. So it means `noOfPurchases` in the Customers table should be 17. And all customers data should be updated it is not that I should put as a input customerID one by one. So how can I do that?

**Order**

| ISBN | customerID | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8670081874189 | 2901 | 30 |
| 333488387049 | 2901 | 20 |
| 6137027197872 | 3421 | 18 |
| 333488387049 | 3683 | 15 |

**Customer**

| customerID | c_firstname | c_surname | noOfPurchases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2901 | john | smith | null |
| 3421 | lisa | jones | null |
| 3683 | alan | jenkins | null |

Comment: I wouldn't do this if I were you. Unless, of course, you *want* to induce a performance problem. Not every attribute of a report needs to be part of the physical schema.

Comment: Please don't post an *image* of text - just post the text. Also, be sure NOT to post real emails, addresses or phone numbers - always obfuscate them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a straightforward multi table UPDATE as described in the manual page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

```
update customer 
join (select customerid, sum(quantity) qty from `orrder` group by customerid) csum
on  customer.customerid = csum.customerid
set nofpurchases = csum.qty;
```

You can either run this manually or periodically using https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html

or if you wish to update on an insert to orrder use a trigger https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

```
delimiter $$
create trigger t after insert on `orrder`
for each row
begin
 update customer
  set nofpurchases = nofpurchases + new.quantity
  where customer.customerid = new.customerid;
end $$
delimiter ;
```